# Capture lead Id field from Cloudpage link sent through SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, form, cloudpagesurl, link

I have created two cloud pages.

1. Cloud page form.
2. thank you page.

I used Cloudpage(URl) function in the email and sent the email, the customer fills the form and the data is stored In the data extension, I am using Inserta data function on the thankyou page, until here everything works fine for email, but not for SMS.

I know the cloudpage(URL) function will not work in SMS until there is subscriber/contactId present in the all subscribers list as the cloudpage UrL function works on email data.

Is there any other way through which I can get this working?

I want to capture the lead Id and other fields filled in the form and the cloud page url will be sent by SMS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the lead id as a query string to the url:

```
Set @leadid = …
Set @url = concat("https://mcxxxxx.cloudpage.com/form?id=", @leadid)
```

And then use the query parameter function on the cloudpage to retrieve the lead id:

```
Set @leadid = QueryParameter('id')
```

Docu: https://ampscript.guide/queryparameter/

Comment: thank you for your Inputs, does it also work without using Cloudpage URL function?

Comment: Yes thats the whole point of adding the qs to the link

Comment: Great! Thanks alot:)

Comment: If this answer helped, please remember to accept it by ticking the check mark- thanks!